# Chasing down an error in my SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I'm just starting out with PHP. I am self-teaching by reading and viewing tuts on PHP and mostly cut and paste snippets together to achieve my results. I am however, familiar with HTML and javascript.

Here's my error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, category, subcategory, date_added, vendor) VALUES('ItemCode','NameofProdu' at line 1
```

The code that I believe causes this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (part, product_name, units, cost, price, details, group, category, subcategory, date_added, vendor) VALUES('$part','$product_name','$units','$cost','$price','$details','$group','$category','$subcategory',now(),'$vendor')") or die (mysql_error());
 $pid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Heres a look at MySQL table:

### products

```
Field           Type               Null

id              int(11)            No       
part            varchar(11)        No       
product_name    varchar(255)       No       
units           int(11)            No       
cost            varchar(16)        No       
price           varchar(16)        No       
details         text               No       
group           varchar(32)        No       
category        varchar(32)        No       
subcategory     varchar(32)        No       
date_added      date               No       
vendor          varchar(32)        No
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: group is reserved keyword and can not be used as column name without surrounding backticks

Comment: mysql  is deprecated use mysqli/PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the field name `group` or enclose it with quotes, it is a reserved keyword in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

`Group` is reserved keyword so you should enclose column names into ``

Answer (score 0):

You should use back tick character (`) with group eg:

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (part, product_name, units, cost, price, details,`group`, category, subcategory, date_added, vendor) VALUES('$part','$product_name','$units','$cost','$price','$details','$group','$category','$subcategory',now(),'$vendor')") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysql_insert_id();

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (part, product_name, units, cost, price, details, `group`, category, subcategory, date_added, vendor) VALUES('$part','$product_name','$units','$cost','$price','$details','$group','$category','$subcategory',now(),'$vendor')") or die (mysql_error());
```