# SQL syntax error, in my user system

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Been sitting here all morning trying to improve safety when users create a new user in my system. And finally when everything is fixed and everything works, and at the end of the code where i send informations to the database, im getting a SQL syntax error *sigh*!!

Here's the error i get:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by) VALUES('tester', 'blabla', 'xx', 'bla@bla.dk', '1387708599', './gfx/profilbi' at line 1`

And heres my code..

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO brugere (brugernavn, kodeord, salt_encrypt, email, timestamp,      img, ip, status, by) VALUES('$_POST[brugernavn]', '$_POST[kode]', 'vissevasse', '$_POST[email]', '$time', '$uploadfile', '$ip_adresse', '0', '$_POST[by]') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

hope you guys can spot this one, because i can't!

Comment: Same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728536/chasing-down-an-error-in-my-sql-syntax#comment31055673_20728536 but in your case `by` is this reserved keyword

Comment: Can you say SQL Injection?

Comment: There IS a clue in the error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
by
```

is a [reserved mysql keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

even when you code no longer will throw an error it is HIGHLY advisable that you do NOT use something like

```
'$_POST[brugernavn]'
```

directly in a query. Google for sql injection [and maybe also consider what xkcd has to say about this](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

`BY` is a mysql reserved keyword you need to wrap it with back-ticks

```
INSERT INTO brugere (`brugernavn`, `kodeord`, `salt_encrypt`, `email`, `timestamp`, `img`, `ip`, `status`, `by`) ....
```

[**Reserved Words in MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.
fetch post parameter using

```
$something = mysqli_real_eacape_string($_POST['<something>']);
```

and then use that variable in your insert query.

Also since mysql is deprecated use mysqli/PDO

Answer (score 0):

For reserved mysql keyword try to use  back tick character (`)

eg:
INSERT INTO users `(`by`)` VALUES ('Jibran')